# Define OnClickListener methods for TextViews that were created dynamically

Tags: android, touch-event, onclicklistener

I created new TextViews in my GUI dynamically and I collected them in an array of TextViews, but I can't set up OnClickListeners because of that (they're inside of an array)...

So what I want to do now is evaluate if the TextView is clicked and handle that event, but I'm not sure how to do so...

If I'm not being to clear, please tell so I can write down the problem with all the details...

Thanks!

Comment: People volunteer their time here to answer your questions, please "repay" the favor by clicking the checkmark in the answers to your previous questions that have helped you. Later when you have more reputation you should upvote any answer that is useful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even when you are creating rows dynamically you still have a reference to the TextView. Simply add the OnClickListener to this reference, like this:

```
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setText(string);
tv1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Do something
    }
});
row.addView(tv1);
```

Answer (score 0):

So your TextViews are in an array like `TextView[] textViews`?

Just call `textViews[0].setOnClickListener()`.

If you used an ArrayList, then it would be `textViews.get(0).setOnClickListener()`